# How to bind repeater in asp.net using for loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

```
String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select FriendTable.UserId from FriendTable inner join UserTable on UserTable.Id = FriendTable.FriendId Where FriendTable.FriendId='" + Session["ID"].ToString() + "' And FriendTable.Status='Request'", con))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             sda.Fill(ds, "FriendTable.UserId");
            
             foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptrRequest.Items)
             {
                 int i = 0;

                 for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                 {
                     SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From UserTable Where Id='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserId"].ToString() + "'", con);
                     SqlDataAdapter sdap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmmd);
                     DataTable dtBrands = new DataTable();
                     sdap.Fill(dtBrands);
                     rptrRequest.DataSource = dtBrands;
                     rptrRequest.DataBind();
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Is this about asp.net WebForms or Asp.Net Core?

Comment: And a question with an actual problem that you are facing, would be nice for us to work with. We currently do not know, what you are trying to achieve, although we could take guesses.

Comment: how data using looping through dataset and show each record ?? its Asp.net Core